# What happens if you call an overridden method using super in a constructor

Tags: java, constructor, super

There is two classes `Super1` and `Sub1`

Super1.class

```
public class Super1 {
    Super1 (){
        this.printThree();
    }

    public void printThree(){
        System.out.println("Print Three");
    }    
}
```

Sub1.class

```
public class Sub1 extends Super1 {
    Sub1 (){
        super.printThree();
    }

    int three=(int) Math.PI;

    public void printThree(){
        System.out.println(three);
    }

    public static void main(String ...a){
         new Sub1().printThree();
    }
}
```

When I invoke the method `printThree` of class `Sub1` I expected the output to  be:

> Print Three
>   3

Because `Sub1` constructor calling the `super.printThree();`.

**But I actually get**

> 0
>   Print Three
>   3

I know 0 is default value of `int` but how it is happening ?

Comment: a constructor calls super(); implicit.

Comment: I want to add that you should never call a method in your constructor that can be overridden (exactly like in your case).  Why? Your overridden method is using a field that is not set (three field).

Comment: You got pretty good answers already, but i would also add this is perfect example why composition is always preferable over inheritance, if situation allows it. Inheritance is wolf in sheep clothing.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're seeing the effects of three things:

1. Default super-constructor calls, and
2. Instance initializers relative to super calls, and
3. How overridden methods work

Your `Sub1` constructor is **really** this:

```
Sub1(){
    super();               // <== Default super() call, inserted by the compiler
    three=(int) Math.PI;   // <== Instance initializers are really inserted
                           // into constructors by the compiler
    super.printThree();
}
```

(Surprising, I know, but it's true. Use `javap -c YourClass` to look. :-) )

The *reason* it looks like that is that the superclass must have a chance to initialize its part of the object *before* the subclass can initialize *its* part of the object. So you get this kind of interwoven effect.

And given that that's what `Sub1` *really* looks like, let's walk through it:

1. The JVM creates the instance and sets all instance fields to their defaults (all bits off). So at this point, the `three` field exists, and has the value `0`.
2. The JVM calls `Sub1`.
3. `Sub1` immediately calls `super()` (`Super1`), which...

   1. ...calls `printThree`. Since `printThree` is overridden, even though the call to it is in the code for `Super1`, it's the *overridden* method (the one in `Sub1`) that gets called. This is part of how Java implements polymorphism. Since `three`'s instance initializer hasn't been run yet, `three` contains `0`, and that's what gets output.
   2. `Super1` returns.
4. Back in `Sub1`, the instance initializer code for `three` that the compiler inserted (relocated, really) runs and gives `three` a new value.
5. `Sub1` calls `printThree`. Since `three`'s instance initializer code has now run, `printThree` prints `3`.

With regard to this instance initializer code getting moved into the constructor, you might be wondering: What if I have more than one constructor? Which one does the code get moved into? The answer is that the compiler *duplicates the code* into each constructor. (You can see that in `javap -c`, too.) (If you have a really complicated instance initializer, I wouldn't be surprised if the compiler effectively turned it into a method, but I haven't looked.)

It's a bit clearer if you do something really naughty and call a method during your instance init: ([live copy](http://ideone.com/y2uGWY))

```
class Super
{
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        new Sub();
    }

    Super() {
        System.out.println("Super constructor");
        this.printThree();
    }

    protected void printThree() {
        System.out.println("Super's printThree");
    }
}
class Sub extends Super
{
    int three = this.initThree();

    Sub() {
        this.printThree();
    }

    private int initThree() {
        System.out.println("Sub's initThree");
        return 3;
    }

    protected void printThree() {
        System.out.println("Sub's printThree: " + this.three);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Super constructor
Sub's printThree: 0
Sub's initThree
Sub's printThree: 3
```

Note where "Sub's initThree" came in that sequence.

Answer (score 3):

When the instance is created, the `Sub1` constructor is called.

The first instruction in *any* constructor is a call to the superclass constructor. If you don't have an explicit call, there will be an implicit call to the no-args constructor of `Super1`.

The no-args constructor is calling `this.printThree()`. This method is overridden in `Sub1`. Now, this part may be confusing, but even if the code is in the superclass, `this.method()` still refers to the overriding method.

So it's calling the `printThree()` in `Sub1`, which prints the uninitialized value of the variable `three` - `0`.

Now that the superclass's constructor is done, it completes `Sub1` constructor, which uses `super.printThree()`. Since it specifically says `super`, the method from `Super1` is used rather than the overriding one. This prints the `Print Three`.

Now the `Sub1` constructor is also done, and `main` calls the new instance's `printThree()`. Now `three` is already initialized, so you get the output `3`.

Comment: that is good one but in super1 class i am using this keyword  for calling the current class method i.e, of super1#printThree but u r stated above its called the sub1#printThree by technique polymorphism then what is the meaning of this keyword here?

Comment: The meaning is that you are using the `printThree()` of the current object, rather than some other object (if you had any other object). `this` always refers to the actual runtime class of the object, which is `Sub1`.

Comment: sorry but still i had confusion :(

Comment: It means "check what implementation of `printThree` is currently, at runtime, in this object, and use that implementation". So because at runtime "this object" is an object of type `Sub1`, the implementation that will be ran is the one from `Sub1`.

Answer (score 0):

While previous answers gave you clear answer to what is happening, they did not gave you any pointers on how to avoid your problems in the future, so I would also like to add my input on this.

If you are going to inherit, then you should make the super class constructor as "dumb" as possible. For example

```
public class Super{
private int a,b;
 public Super(int a, int b) {
 this.a = a;
 this.b = b;
 }
//all the methods operating on the data provided by constructor
}
```

and then having sub constructor like this

```
  private int c,d;
    public Sub(int a, int b) {
    super(a,b);
    c = a;
    d = b;
    }
```

Is perfectly fine and is going to give you minimal side-effects, while keeping the functionality of the parent class.

But having

```
public Super(){
method1();
method2();
}
```

and then having sub do this

```
public Sub(){
super.method1();
super.method2();
}
```

Is really asking for trouble and possible hard to track bugs. The less the object does during initialization, the better, because it gives the childs flexibility.
Managing inheritance is like being dumb manager vs clever manager. Dumb manager calls Tim and Tracy employee, because they are both employees, and their jobs as Accountant and HR manager are just tags. Clever manager knows Tim and Tracy are Accountant and Manager and does not care that much that they are basically just employees.

Comment: `super(c,d)` ... are you sure about that?

Comment: Yeah my bad, long time since I used inheritance and did not check if my code is valid. Thanks.